# Integrate seccomp profile into Docker image

Tags: docker, seccomp

I have a seccomp profile for my Golang app (generated with [go2seccomp](https://github.com/xfernando/go2seccomp)) to use with Docker but would like not to have to use it on the command line with `--security-opt`. Is there a way to "integrate" the profile while building the image? One reason is to avoid having an extra file and be able to `docker run` it directly.

Maybe I'm not understanding how Docker and seccomp work together, or maybe this is just not an available feature.

Comment: As a general rule, a Docker image can’t define itself to have elevated privileges; these always must be given by the operator in a `docker run` command or equivalent.

Comment: I see, thanks. So there's no convenient way besides downloading the tailored seccomp profile for the dockerized app on another channel ?